# how to set smooth scrolling offset when it is reached width <480 px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.smooth-scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var section = $(this).attr("href"); //get or return section id #about etc

        var section = $(this).attr("href");
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(section).offset().top - 64
        }, 1250, "easeInOutExpo");
    });


});
```

This the code for smooth scrolling. It is working correctly in desktop screen but when it comes to mobile devices   i need to set the offset().top-64 to offset().top-50.How to do that? I tried using resize function but is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to check the current window size, and set the value of 50 or 64 according to width you got.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a.smooth-scroll").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var section = $(this).attr("href"); //get or return section id #about etc

    var section = $(this).attr("href");
    var value = ($(window).width() < 480) ? 50 : 64);
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(section).offset().top - value
    }, 1250, "easeInOutExpo");
});
```